# effective folder permissions

Tags: linux, lamp, file-permissions

I am developing on LAMP and have come to understand that folders need execute permissions in order to use the files within them. Does this mean that `chmod 100` is where I should start for most of these? Do read permissions do anything on a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read permissions on a folder is needed to list the content of the folder, in other words, do a `ls`

Comment: I appear to be able to list contents without read permission and just execute permissions- is that right?